# Is a discursive answer to a succinct question acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers

I just stumbled across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44650423/1313143) and I seriously doubt the quality of it, but I'm not sure if it is fine to just stay.

It takes a great "detour" to actually answer the question, by drawing a rather far-fetched analogy with the concept asked about by the OP. What bugs me most is that it also involves names like "Donald Trump" and "Spaghetti monster", i.e. it's extremely chatty at best.

I've explored some topics from the help center but couldn't find any concrete  rules or restrictions that the answer violates.

What is the community's stance on it?

Comment: What is your stance on this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Comment: If it doesn't violate any rules and it does actually answer the question, then vote with your... um, votes.

Comment: There is a liability to answering a question while intoxicated, I can personally attest.  Although judging from his profile, that might be a consistent state of mind.  Somebody commented he'd "add +2 if he could", doesn't sound like he meant faces.  Good enough.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not a fan of questions or answers that needlessly introduce politics. I don't see how a cliché joke about the current U.S. President helps an answer about .NET at all, and in fact it detracts from it.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, a joke at someone's expense could run foul of the "Rudeness and belittling language are not okay" or "Don't be a jerk" bullet-points in the [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: No matter what the target of a joke is, it's going to offend some snowflake somewhere, that's the new world we live in. I don't think we should stop cracking the odd joke because of it to be honest. It's a bit of a stretch to mix in the be-nice-policy over that analogy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Politics aside, some people find analogies to be rather helpful in understanding concepts.  Vote on whether you think the analogy is accurate and helpful in answering the question.  If you think the analogy is offensive or inappropriate, you can comment, edit, or flag depending on how egregious you think it is.

In this particular case, the author admits

> Granted, the analogy is a bit strained, but I hope it is helpful to someone.

so maybe this answer deserves a downvote.  Personally, I found the analogy way too long-winded and distracting, so if I had found it naturally, I would have downvoted.  But it attempts to answer the question and shouldn't be deleted.